# How to know which file(its filename, path...) is uploaded successfully of onCompletion in DriveEventService

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to know which file (its file name, info and so on) is uploaded successfully in `onCompletion` of `DriveEventService` after `fileCallback` is called using `createFile`.

Now I could not connect the driveID in the `fileCallback` with the one in `onCompletion` of `DriveEventService`. How could I do?
Thanks.

The drive IDs are different in these two callback:

```
10-13 16:39:12.879 20895 20895 I gerald1111: onResume

10-13 16:39:12.889 20895 20895 I gerald1111: connect start

10-13 16:39:12.899 20895 20895 I gerald1111: connect start end

10-13 16:39:13.389 20895 20895 I gerald1111: GoogleApiClient connected

10-13 16:39:14.059 20895 20895 I gerald1111: createFile: createfile start

10-13 16:39:14.769 20895 20895 I gerald1111: Created a file: DriveId:CAESABjmDSCAooG5p1E=

10-13 16:39:17.749 20895 21373 I gerald1111: Commit completed successfully: DriveId:CAESHDBCLVhkeGJ4eXBhQ01TMjV3YzA4MFQy
OUtNR00Y5g0ggKKBuadR,
```

Comment: What are you logging from the drive id?  The drive id when completed will now have a resource id in it, so toString won't necessarily match.

Comment: Hi Cheryl,  thanks for response. 1. public void onResult(DriveFileResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                showMessage("Error while trying to create the file");
                return;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Created a file: " + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId());
     } 2. @Override
     public void onCompletion(CompletionEvent event) {
        if (event.getStatus() == CompletionEvent.STATUS_SUCCESS) {
             // Commit completed successfully.
          Log.i(TAG, "Commit completed successfully: "+ event.getDriveId());
     }
   }

Comment: As I know, the resource id seemed useless? Now I only use encodeToString to retrieve drive file information. However, their encodeToStrings are also different...

Comment: And I did not know which file I just create, it was uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 1):

### IDs in the Android API

**[DriveIds](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveId.html):** *Locally unique object*. The main IDs used in the Drive Android API. Available from the moment a resource has been created via [`getDriveId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveResource.html#getDriveId()), even if it hasn't been uploaded.

**ResourceIds:** *Globally unique string*. The main IDs used in the Drive Web API (also known as [`fileId`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files)). Available **only after** a file has been uploaded to the server via [`getResourceId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveId.html#getResourceId()) (it will return null if the file hasn't been uploaded). You can get a DriveId for a given resourceId using [`fetchDriveId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi.html#fetchDriveId(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String)).

**Warning!** Persisted DriveIds will be invalidated if Google Play services data is cleared. ResourceIds should be used for long term referencing.

### Comparison

DriveIds should **always** be compared with [`equals()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveId.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

The string representation of a DriveId returned by [`encodeToString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveId.html#encodeToString()) changes based on whether a resourceId is available. If you are persisting the string representation, you can use [`decodeFromString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveId.html#decodeFromString(java.lang.String)) to convert it back to a DriveId in order to compare.

**Warning!** [`toString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveId.html#toString()) is not guaranteed to return the same result as encodeToString, and should not be used for persistence.

ResourceIds can be compared using string comparison, but as noted above, they are only available once a file has been uploaded.

### Matching completion events to local files

Here are two options you could use to identify which local file has been uploaded when receiving a [`CompletionEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/events/CompletionEvent.html):

**Use HashMaps:**

1. After creating a file, add the the DriveId and file path to a `<DriveId, String>` HashMap.

   - **Warning!** As mentioned above, make sure you use the DriveId objects, not the encodeToString representation as that may change.
2. Get the DriveId from the [`CompletionEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/events/CompletionEvent.html#getDriveId()) and use that to lookup the file path in the HashMap.

**Use Tracking Tags:**

1. When creating a file, put the file path in the ExecutionOptions tracking tag using [`setTrackingTag()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/ExecutionOptions.Builder.html#setTrackingTag(java.lang.String)).
2. Check the tracking tag in the [`CompletionEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/events/CompletionEvent.html#getTrackingTags()) to get the file path of the
   uploaded file.